the canonical decomposition of a function with a relation
let $E,F$ two sets and a function $f:E\to F$ , a relation $R$ is defined on $E$ with
$$\forall (x,y)\in E^{2} , xRy\iff f(x)=f(y)$$
$R$ is an equivalence relation and the equivalence class of x is $\bar{x}=\{y\in E;f(x)=f(y) \}=f^{-1}(\{f(y)\})$
now we have a function $\bar{f:}E/R\to F$ defined by $\bar{f}(\bar{x})=f(x)$
and it is well defined , the question was to prove that $\bar{f}$ is injective, and it is easy to prove , just conclude that for 2 elemnts with the same images we have that they are in relation with $R$
they didnt ask for surjectivity but it is also .
but there is question i stiil cant find an answer for
they said :
What we can conclude about the quotient set ??
i dont have any idea , some help please

Maybe the fact that for each $z \in F$ there is an element $\overline x$ in the quotient set $E/R$ such that $z=f(x)$?

Or maybe just the fact that $|E/R| \leq |F|$?

We can conclude many things; who knows what your teacher has in mind. This question is not answerable.

@JeanAbouSamra they are equal, No??

@NaïmFavier example?? What we can conclude also
